# PySerial permission denied when invoked by webserver

Tags: python, django, permissions, uwsgi, cherokee

I have a django application which connects to several serial devices on the server.

This application is running on Ubuntu 10.04.  The user "chero" is the owner of the webserver processes.  chero is a member of the dialout group.

Everything works as expected using the development server, or a python shell (running as user chero).

The webserver is cherokee, with uwsgi (also running as chero).  When the webserver tries to open a serial port I get: [error 13] permission denied.

I have verified that the webserver is indeed running as user chero by inserting this in the line before the serial port would be opened:
raise ValueError('user: ' + pwd.getpwuid( os.getuid() ).pw_name)

The webserver was able to open the port after I set permissions on /dev/ttyS* to 666, but that is not an ideal solution.

Is there some reason uwsgi or cherokee would prevent chero from being recognized as a member of the dialout group?